# Unable to see a web part page in Form Library since view panel is missing

Tags: site-collection, web-part-pages, forms-library

After creating a WebPart Page 'abc.aspx' under site collection 'MySiteCol' , I was unable to view it under form library. Although it showed 1 item, but the no file was visible inside it.

Also the view,upload,edit pane is missing inside form library.How to bring  back that view pane?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the 'new,upload,action' pane .Somehow it got missing. But after inserting another form library template, i am able to view the pages.

Under advanced webpart control, adding a new form library template would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the page with a different user account? If versioning is enabled in the library the page will only be visible to the creator until he checks in the page. With administrative rights you can also view the checked out files in the library settings and take their ownership.

Comment: thanks for the help.. the problem was with the 'new,upload,action' pane .Somehow it got missing. But after inserting another form library template, i am able to view the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the page was created in another library?

Do you have publishing features activated? In that case, there should be a Pages library containing the ASPX pages.